# Unable to understand how to typecast and get values out of a backtrace in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, gdb, structure

I used to work with Java and C++ and now work in a company which primarily programs in C. I almost every other day need to run a gdb on a daemon and get the backtrace. I am never fully able to understand how to get the values out of the structure properly.

Let me give an example:

lets say we have 4 structures:

```
 typedef struct profile_s{
      int x;
      int y;
      gold_t *gold;
    }profile_t;
    
    typedef struct copper_s{
      int price;
      profile_t *prof;
    }copper_t;
    
    typedef struct gold_s{
      int cost;
    }gold_t;
    
    void foo(copper_t *var){
    copper_t *variable = var; 
    bar();
    }
    
    void bar(){
    }
```

Now if we want to obtain values of profile and gold, we can obtain those from copper_t pointer variable. I am not sure how to obtain these.

If GDB for this code is on foo function, we can obtain copper pointer value.

When typecasting copper pointer val, why does (copper_t *) variable not work and (copper_t) * variable work in gdb ?

Also, similarly if we wanted to obtain profile and gold values out of this pointer, we will have to typecast those pointers to their respective structures.
now if we do (copper_t) *variable->prof, it gives me profile pointer. How to typecast this expression to get x and y out of it.

p (profile_t)(copper_t) *variable->prof is incorrect.

What is correct expression to get the value ?

Also similarly for gold, how to get (gold_t)(profile_t)(copper_t)variable->prof->gold

Hoping to get some clarity regarding the same.

```
Edit:
(gdb) p variable->prof
$21 = (profile_t *) 0x7f2bd3343e60
(gdb) p variable
$22 = (copper_t *) 0x7f2a4d202040
(gdb) p (copper_t) *variable
$23 = {
  price = 100,
  prof = 0x7f2bd3343e60,
 
}
```

Now I want to get the profile structure values from this pointer. How to get that.

Also, why would (copper_t) *variable work and (copper_t *)variable print only pointer value.

Ex:

```
(gdb) p (copper_t *) variable
$24 = (copper_t *) 0x7f2a4d202040
```

Comment: The code you have shown is both incomplete and syntactically not valid C code. Please provide an exact [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Include exact complete code and exact complete gdb log.

Comment: Hi @kaylum I am afraid I might not be able to copy code due to company restrictions. That is why I have added a dummy code which is similar. Stackoverflow was deleting * from my post, I have edited it again to reflect the * in my post.

Comment: Not asking for full code. In fact we don't want it. We want a complete minimal example that illustrates your problem. That means complete code that anyone can build exactly as shown and the gdb commands to run exactly as shown to reproduce what you are seeing.

Comment: Emphasis on minimal, which is often the one aspect of MCV that causes you to solve your own problem. Minimize until the problem goes away. Then put back the thing that causes death.

Comment: Hi @kaylum. I have edited the post. hope it makes it more clear. I am just trying to print structure values in gdb to see what values the member variables of each struct have. I am not able to typecast the pointers correctly.

Comment: That's not valid C code.  `profile_t{ ..} ` is not how structs are declared in C. It's still unclear what you problem is as you have still not provided an exact gdb log. There should be no typecasting needed. You simply need to do `p variable->prof` to print that structure. Perhaps you are not building with full debugging info. But without the log it is difficult to say for sure.

Comment: Hi @kaylum Edited again. It will not print everything in one shot. It is a pointer and not a static variable. I have edited the code again to reflect that.

Comment: `p *variable->prof` will print the whole structure contents. No typecasting needed.

Comment: @kaylum Mind == blown because till date I was typecasting like crazy. Any which ways, if the pointer var was of type void which could be typecasted into (copper_t), and then I had to obtain prof and gold from it, then how would I go about doing that typecasting ?

Comment: Sorry but it's impossible to understand the problem from this sloppy pseudo code. Please provide a [mcve] instead.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a few questions here:

Why do the following 2 commands have different results in gdb?

```
p (copper_t *) variable

p (copper_t) *variable
```

In the first case, the typecast applies to the expression **variable** and tells gdb to treat **variable** as being a pointer to a **copper_t**.  As seen in the earlier output of **p variable**, gdb is already aware that **variable** is a pointer to a **copper_t**, so the typecast is unnecessary can be left off, leaving the equivalent **p variable** which just prints the pointer.

In the second case gdb first forms the expression ***variable**.  Given that gdb knows the type of **variable** to be a pointer to a **copper_t**, gdb knows that ***variable** is of type copper_t.  So again the typecast is unnecessary and you could just use the command **p** ***variable** , which prints out a **copper_t** structure.

In summary you could have used the following commands to print the pointer and the target of the pointer, respectively.

```
p variable

p *variable
```

How does one print out the profile?

```
p *(variable->prof)
```

How does one print out the x and y values for the profile, as opposed to the entire profile?

```
p variable->prof->x
p variable->prof->y
```

How does one print out the gold structure associated with that variable?

```
p *(variable->prof->gold)
```